# Is it possible: Pass a C++ QWidget Object to PyQt Script?

Tags: python, qt

The main application is written in C++, and I can't rewrite it in other language.
Can I pass a C++ QWidget Object to PyQt Script so that in the script I can add a QButton to the QWidget ?

Any help would be  appreciated

Comment: I don't think so (not sanely anyway) unless the application was built with that in mind. Why no just update the C++ code if you just want to add a button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can as long as you have a way to locate that widget from PyQt.

For example, if the widget has an easy to remember object name like "MyWidgetFromCpp" you can call:

```
cppWidget = PyQt.QtGui.QApplication.instance().findChild("MyWidgetFromCpp")
```

You might need to call the findChild() function for every QApplication top level widget (returned by topLevelWidgets()) in case the findChild() function doesn't search deep enough.